# Set condition that keeps right number input

Tags: javascript

I need to make an IF in JS code. There are some conditions for the number input:

- allowed numbers: **1, 2, 34, 68, 136, 272, 544**
- numbers 545 and above is allowed only when **number%5 == 0**
- max allowed number is **4000**

Is there any easy way how to put these condition into just one IF?

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a function to test the values, testNumber with one if statement, by using Array.includes to test the number and then checking if the value is between 545 and 4000 and is divisible by 5.

```js
/* Number must be one of [1, 2, 34, 68, 136, 272, 544] OR be between
   545 and 4000 and divisible by 5 */
function testNumber(n) {
    const allowedNumbers = [1, 2, 34, 68, 136, 272, 544];
    return ((allowedNumbers.includes(n)) || ((n >= 545) && (n <= 4000) && (n % 5 === 0)));
}

const testValues = [ 
 { n: 1, expectedResult: true},
 { n: 34, expectedResult: true},
 { n: 4000, expectedResult: true},
 { n: 0, expectedResult: false},
 { n: 546, expectedResult: false},
 { n: 4001, expectedResult: false},
];

console.log(`testNumber: All ${testValues.length} tests pass:`, testValues.every(({n, expectedResult}) => testNumber(n) === expectedResult))
```

We could also generate the allowed ranges, using Array.from:

```js
/* Number must be one of [1, 2, 34, 68, 136, 272, 544] OR be between
   545 and 4000 and divisible by 5 */
function testNumberII(n) {
    const range1 = [1, 2, 34, 68, 136, 272, 544];
    const range2 = Array.from( { length: 1 + (4000 - 545) / 5 }, (v,k) => 545 + k*5);
    return range1.includes(n) || range2.includes(n);
}

const testValues = [ 
 { n: 1, expectedResult: true},
 { n: 34, expectedResult: true},
 { n: 4000, expectedResult: true},
 { n: 0, expectedResult: false},
 { n: 546, expectedResult: false},
 { n: 4001, expectedResult: false},
];

console.log(`testNumberII: All ${testValues.length} tests pass:`, testValues.every(({n, expectedResult}) => testNumberII(n) === expectedResult))
```